# Sorting by character first in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I need to sort the list so that all the string starting with char are sorted first then by string started with number in ascending order. Is there any build in algorithm to do this if not what will be best approach to solve this?

```
Doctor Review
3rd Party Contact
Appointment
24-Hour Service
Doctor Preparation
```

to

```
Appointment
Doctor Preparation
Doctor Review
3rd Party Contact
24-Hour Service
```

I am trying to write custom Comparator like [this](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html) but not sure how I group string starting with character and digit.

Comment: No builtin algorithm, no, but you can write your custom `Comparator`. Also, what should happen for characters which are not in the ASCII set?

Comment: You can find an example of such a Comparator [here](http://zoril.co.uk/wp/2011/11/sorting-in-java-letters-first/), it will sort by letter first and by numbers.

Comment: I would look into writing a custom `Comparator` class, like @fge said.

Comment: In what order do you want `"2nd line"` and `"10 commandments"` sorted?

Comment: The ASCII codes for the numbers 0-9 are between 48 and 57, so you can have something check if the characters are in that ASCII range or not.

Comment: Is it only the first `char` you care about or are you looking to keep the pattern for the entire string compare?  Does `2nd Chance` come before or after `22 Chances`?

Comment: I have updated the question with my requirement. Sort by char first then number in ascending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Doctor Review");
    list.add("3rd Party Contact");
    list.add("Appointment");
    list.add("24-Hour Service");
    list.add("Doctor Preparation");
    ArrayList<String> newlist = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.sort(list);
    for (String x : list)

    {
        if (!Character.isDigit(x.charAt(0))) {
            newlist.add(x);
        }
    }

    for (String x : list)

    {
        if (Character.isDigit(x.charAt(0))) {
            newlist.add(x);
        }
    }
```

Solution, using another list.

Comment: Separate list into two different then sort each list.

Answer (score 1):

As you surmised, a custom `Comparator` is needed.

Now, the difficulty you'll have is with characters outside of the ASCII set; and in particular, since Java stores text data as UTF-16 code units internally, anything outside the BMP will be two `char`s...

But let us say that this is not a problem and that the only thing you care about is "good old" Arabic numbers, which happen to be representable with a single `char`.

Then this is how you could write such a comparator (**UNTESTED!**):

```
public static final Comparator<String> ARABIC_NUMBERS_LAST_COMPARATOR
    = new Comparator<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(final String o1, final String o2)
        {
            return doCompare(CharBuffer.wrap(o1), CharBuffer.wrap(o2));
        }

        private int doCompare(final CharBuffer buf1, final CharBuffer buf2)
        {
            // Test for the emptiness of each buffer
            final int r1 = buf1.remaining();
            final int r2 = buf2.remaining();
            if (r1 == 0)
                return r2 == 0 ? 0 : -1;
            if (r2 == 0)
                return 1; // we know that r1 is not empty here

            // Grab the first character from both buffers
            final char c1 = buf1.get();
            final char c2 = buf2.get();

            // If both characters are the same we must continue
            if (c1 == c2)
                return doCompare(buf1, buf2);

            // They are not... Test whether either of them is a digit
            final boolean oneIsDigit = Character.isDigit(c1);
            final boolean twoIsDigit = Character.isDigit(c2);

            // Both are digits: return what the contract expects
            if (oneIsDigit && twoIsDigit)
                return c1 - c2;

            // From this point on we know that at least one character is
            // not a digit, and that they are both different.
            if (oneIsDigit)
                return 1;
            if (twoIsDigit)
                return -1;
            // Both are not digits, but we know them to be different:
            // just return the difference
            return c1 - c2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're performing a recursive call. Why do we need to check the second character if the first ones are the same? I guess we just need to know if the first character is a digit or not and how to compare it with the first digit of the second String. If I see it correctly, your code already does this correctly.

Comment: If the first ones are the same we still need and compare the second one and further, right? Note that I know that this code is not ideal...

Comment: *"If the first ones are the same we still need and compare the second one and further, right?"* Yes, but the normal String comparision could do that for us :D. *"Note that I know that this code is not ideal..."* There is always a better version, so "ideal" is hard to reach anyway :D.

Comment: The reason that I didn't go for the string comparison further on is that it would have required to create substrings here; instead I proceed character by character. Of course, there could have been the better option of using `CharBuffer` instead.

Comment: Rewritten using `CharBuffer`s; and fixed a bug in the process :p

Comment: *"that it would have required to create substrings here"* Why? Do we care about the second character? All we need to know is the first character of both Strings. If both have either digits or characters: String comparision, if 1 has a digit and 2 a character: **1** and **-1** for the opposite case. Like @kg_sYys answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
public class TryMe {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> sortMe = new ArrayList<>();
    sortMe.add("Doctor Review");
    sortMe.add("3rd Party Contact");
    sortMe.add("Appointment");
    sortMe.add("24-Hour Service");
    sortMe.add("Doctor Preparation");
    Collections.sort(sortMe, new MyComparator());
    System.out.println(sortMe);
  }

  private static class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
      if (Character.isDigit(o1.charAt(0))) {
        if (Character.isDigit(o2.charAt(0))) {
          //replace here with "return o1.compareTo(o2)" for original
          int i1 = getFirstDigits(o1);
          int i2 = getFirstDigits(o2);
          if (i1 == i2) return o1.compareTo(o2);
          return i1 - i2;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      }
      if (Character.isDigit(o2.charAt(0))) return -1;
      return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
  }

  private static int getFirstDigits(String from) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < from.length() ; i++) {
      if (!Character.isDigit(from.charAt(i))) {
        return Integer.parseInt(from.substring(0, i));
      }
    }
    if (i > 0) return Integer.parseInt(from.substring(0, i));
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No digits to parse, should not happen");
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I make '3rd Party Contact' come first before '24-Hour Service' in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own [RuleBasedCollator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html) (see `myrules` in code below).

This approach works for numbers after the first position too!

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Doctor Review");
    list.add("Doctor Review A"); // check sort order of this entry!
    list.add("Doctor Review 1"); // check sort order of this entry!
    list.add("3rd Party Contact");
    list.add("Appointment");
    list.add("24-Hour Service");
    list.add("Doctor Preparation");

    String myrules = "< a, A < b, B < c, C < d, D < e, E < f, F < g, G < h, H < i, I" +
        "< j, J < k, K < l, L < m, M < n, N < o, O < p, P < q, Q < r, R" +
        "< s, S < t, T < u, U < v, V < w, W < x, X < y, Y < z, Z" +
        "< 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9";

    try {
      RuleBasedCollator myRuleBasedCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(myrules);
      Collections.sort(list, myRuleBasedCollator);
      for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
      }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Appointment
Doctor Preparation
Doctor Review
Doctor Review A
Doctor Review 1
24-Hour Service
3rd Party Contact
```

Comment: Nice one but this is highly locale dependent (well, String sorting is in general)